# python select the lowest alphanumeric value with a reference from multiple lists

Tags: python, list, comparison, tuples

I have multiple lists like this:

```
#Symbol  ID
['AAA','MG_00013']
['AAA','MG_00177']
['AAA','MG_00005']
['BBB','MG_0045']
['BBB','MG_00080']
['CCC','MG_0002'] # and so on...
```

and I would like to choose the list with a same symbol with the smallest ID.

So, the end result is like this:

```
#Symbol  ID
['AAA','MG_00005']
['BBB','MG_0045']
['CCC','MG_0002'] #...
```

To do that, I have made them into a list of lists

```
listoflists =[['AAA','MG_00013'],['AAA','MG_00177'],['AAA','MG_00005'],['BBB','MG_0045'],['BBB','MG_00080'],['CCC','MG_0002']]
```

I'm lost from here...

```
for i in listoflists:
if i[0] == i[0]:
    test.append(i[1])

for i in test:
    print(i)
```

which gives a False result.

I think the logic is to make them into a list like the below and compare the alphanumeric ID and select the lowest one.

```
[(AAA,['MG_00013','MG_00177','MG_00005'])]
```

However, I'm completely lost and frustrating now...

Could you ,please, help me go through this?

===============================================
Everybody helping me out is so great!
However, the length of ID have to be considered.
For example, everybody gives me BBB wih MG_00080, but it suppose MG_0045 as 45 is less than 80...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ll =[['AAA','MG_00013'],
    ['AAA','MG_00177'],
    ['AAA','MG_00005'],
    ['BBB','MG_0045'],
    ['BBB','MG_00080'],
    ['CCC','MG_0002']]

d = {}
for l in ll:
    # If key is not the dict, insert the entry into dict
    if l[0] not in d:
        d[l[0]] = l[1]
    # If key is already in the dict, update the entry if value is smaller
    elif int(l[1][3:]) < int(d[l[0]][3:]):
        d[l[0]] = l[1]

print d
```

Output:

```
{'AAA': 'MG_00005', 'BBB': 'MG_0045', 'CCC': 'MG_0002'}
```

Comment: wow, This is so crispy clear and the error is fixed. Thank you @Mingyu

Answer (score 4):

I would think something like a dictionary might be better, but this will give your expected output.

```
import itertools

listoflists =[['AAA','MG_00013'],['AAA','MG_00177'],['AAA','MG_00005'],['BBB','MG_0045'],['BBB','MG_00080'],['CCC','MG_0002']]

minlists = [
    min(value, key=lambda lst: lst[1])
    for _, value in itertools.groupby(listoflists, lambda lst: lst[0])
]
print minlists
```

outputs

```
[['AAA', 'MG_00005'], ['BBB', 'MG_00080'], ['CCC', 'MG_0002']]
```

EDIT: The comparison of ids was not clear to me, but to compare them psuedo-numerically (not lexiographically), replace `key=lambda lst: lst[1]` with

```
key=lambda lst: int(lst[1][3:])
```

Comment: This is awesome, Paul, but the length of ID has to be considered as for the symbol 'BBB' the corresponding ID should be 'MG_0045' instead of 'MG_00080', because 45 is less than 80...

Thank you I'm trying to solve it now.

Answer (score 2):

This is a good spot for a `defaultdict`

```
from collections import defaultdict

D = defaultdict(list)
for k,v in listoflists:
    D[k].append(v)

return [[k, min(D[k])] for k in D]
```

Comment: Introducing me defaultdict is really great and this is awesomely simple code, but it cannot consider the psuedo-numerically comparison of the IDs. Thank you.

Comment: Oh, you're right, I forgot about that. For that you would pass `min` a key function, similar to what Paul Draper was trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

You could convert it into the dictionary of lists

```
d = { k[0] : [] for k in listoflists }
for k in listoflists: d[k[0]].append(k[1])
ans = [ [k,min(d[k])] for k in d ]
print ans
```

or just

```
d = { k[0] : [] for k in listoflists }
for k in listoflists: d[k[0]].append(k[1])
for k in d: print k,min(d[k])
```

Comment: Dictionary method that much easily understandable for me. Thank you @lejlot. However, the same problem with answer by Paul Draper. The length of ID has to be considered as for the symbol 'BBB' the corresponding ID should be 'MG_0045' instead of 'MG_00080', because 45 is less than 80... Thank you too!